How can I replace an integrated solid surface sink?
I recently purchased a home and the kitchen sink is a permanent fixture with the countertop. I want to install a single bowl drop-in or under mount sink, but I have no idea if that’s possible with the type of counter/sink combo going on here. Any advice or experience would be appreciated.
Pictures


I'll give my standard advice for new homeowners: Don't go ripping things out until you give them a chance. You might find you actually like how it is, and that saves you effort and money. Wait six months first.

This sink and countertop are made of "solid surface" material, which is an epoxy resin plastic, which can be glued together such that the sink and countertop become one solid mass of plastic. Your countertop is the gray part, and the sink is the white part.
There are two removal options:
A. This sink can be removed from the existing countertop by using a strong router and a router bit consisting of a shaft and saw blade wide enough to cut completely through the flange of the sink that can be seen under the countertop. If done precisely, the full thickness of the countertop material (your gray piece) would be left.
B. The sink can also be removed, if the new sink is large enough, by simply cutting the new sink's required mounting hole. Then the whole existing sink and required portions of the gray countertop would be removed.
In case B, you'd have to be replacing this sink with a new sink requiring a mounting hole larger than the whole top edge of the existing sink. If you find that the new sink's hole does not fully cut away the flange of the old sink, the remaining portions of flange can be cut away with the saw blade router bit from option A.
In either case a new undermount sink can be glued under the countertop and the edge of the countertop can be routed to fit the sink with a special non-scratch router bit. The new sink can even be solid surface, again, and be glued and formed smoothly to the countertop just as the old sink is. Or non-solid-surface undermount sink could be used, or a surface mount sink.

Good answer. If I was doing a retrofit undermount, I’d build enough structure underneath that I wasn’t relying on the epoxy to hold everything together. Self-rimming surface mount would be much easier.

This shouldn't be your first time using a router.. :-)

I'm not sanguine about retrofitting a sink to that counter, though—it looks really thin.
